# PHP - setting a variable to a parameter name conflict

Tags: php

I've been trying for the last two weeks to develop a super simple interface to import users in a mailing list on campaign monitor.

The place I'm stuck has been with getting the array of users into the right format.  I've been back and forth with their support, all over google, and nothing.  The main problem is I've been getting mixed signals from their support staff.  I started digging around in their wrapper file and I saw something that had me a little confused...

```
function import($subscribers, $resubscribe, $queueSubscriptionBasedAutoResponders = false, $restartSubscriptionBasedAutoResponders = false) {
    $subscribers = array(
        'Resubscribe' => $resubscribe,
        'QueueSubscriptionBasedAutoResponders' => $queueSubscriptionBasedAutoResponders,
        'Subscribers' => $subscribers,
        'RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders' => $restartSubscriptionBasedAutoResponders
    );

    return $this->post_request($this->_subscribers_base_route.'/import.json', $subscribers);
}
```

This is the import function they supplied as part of their PHP wrapper.

Now, forgive me if I'm mistaken as I'm no coding genius, but shouldn't they be using a different variable for the main array that's not a function parameters?  If `$subscribers` is set as a function param, would it cause problems if they then immediately set a variable to `$subscribers`?

Comment: no, subscribers is first used in the assignment "'Subscribers' => $subscribers," line.  The value passed in as a parameter is assigned to $subscribers['Subscribers'].

Comment: `$subscribers` is first used in defining the array, on the second line `$subscribers = array(`.

Comment: the assignment precedes the variable creation so the value won't get destroyed. and as @joe42 mentioned the parameter `$subscribers` is safely assigned to variable `$subscribers['Subscribers']`